# Issue with leaflet.js "viewreset" map not zooming out properly

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am new to Leaflet.js. I am trying add a layer to an OSM using Leaflet and D3. I can see one dot but when I zoom out to see if other dots are showing the map is does not redraw properly and I'm getting a "TypeError: t is undefined" message as well.

Here is bulk of my code:

```
/* We simply pick up the SVG from the map object */
var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg"),
g = svg.append("g");

d3.tsv("DH_Doig.tsv", function(data) {
    /* Add a LatLng object to each item in the dataset */
    data.forEach(function(d) {
  if (d.SoundLat && d.SoundLong) {
    d.SoundLat = +d.SoundLat;
    d.SoundLong = +d.SoundLong;
    d.SoundLatLong = new L.LatLng(d.SoundLat, d.SoundLong);
    //d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.circle.coordinates[0],
                                //d.circle.coordinates[1])
                //console.log(d.SoundLatLong)

  }
```

//console.log(d.SoundLatLong);
        })

```
    var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("opacity", .6)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", 20);

    map.on("viewreset", update);
    update();

    function update() {
        feature.attr("transform",
        function(d) {
          console.log(d.SoundLatLong);  //added to see lat long
            return "translate("+
                map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.SoundLatLong).x +","+
                map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.SoundLatLong).y +")";
            }
        )
    }
})
```

The typeError message has is referencing this line:

```
                    map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.SoundLatLong).x +","+
```

I am using this example as a basis: [Map using leaflet.js and d3 combined.](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535)

Here is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/BdFAPmU8gSX1t7kRnBis) of my code.

Comment: Use `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js`, that will give you more meaningful error stack traces.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to leaflet-src.js. I am now getting the message "TypeError: latlng is undefined" . I have added console.log(d.SoundLatLong); (see the code above), the lat long object is being created correctly but I am getting an "undefined" message now relating to the console.log(d.SoundLatLong); line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had some null rows in my tsv, I thought the if (d.SoundLat && d.SoundLong) had caught the nulls but apparently not.